# Split number by X to 2 decimal places and make sure sum is same as original value

Tags: functions

I asked this in a development forum and someone suggested posting here

I need to split an invoice line into (in this instance) 3 parts (each with 2 decimal places), but I have ensure that the sum of the splits adds up to the original value.

For example: if I split 5.13 by 3%, 42% and 55% (each rounded to 2DP) I end up with:

0.15
2.82
2.15
Sum = 5.12

The only way I can figure it out is split all but the last $ and then subtract the sum of those from the original value

e.g.

0.15 + 2.82 = 2.97
5.13 - 3.97 = 2.16

I can do this in the language I'm using, but it's not very efficient.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: BTW, the figures in your percentage list and your dollar list don't match up.

Comment: What would be an acceptable answer to the task of splitting 1.01 into 50% and 50%?

Comment: Would have to be 0.50 and 0.51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is actually one of the *most* efficient: just one multiplication per person, and a simple sum to handle the remainder. However, it's not the fairest. For example, splitting \$0.10 equally between 7 people will end up charging the first 6 people \$0.01 and the last person $0.04. Given that the differences are typically only at the cent level, this may not matter.

If it does matter, you can use a **proportional allocation** method. The simplest is probably the [largest remainder method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method), where allocations are always rounded down and the outstanding quantity is distributed to the parties with the highest remainder. For the above example, that would charge \$0.02 to three parties and \$0.01 to everyone else. Other methods include [highest average methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest_averages_method) such as [D'Hondt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method), which is used in many elections worldwide. All such methods suffer from [apportionment paradoxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apportionment_paradox) but at the cent level this probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate some of those. When I said "not very efficient" I just meant in the language I'm using (SQL), as I have to rank the row (one query), calculate the split for all but the last (or largest) row, then use another (sub) select to sum those rows and subtract from total. So it's actually 3 queries instead of one. I was therefore trying to figure out if there was some way of a applying a calculation in a single select. As it's just to apportion $'s to accounting splits, I can live with rounding of a few cents

Answer (score 2):

You may want to employ methods also used in elections to distribute parliamentary seats, such as [Hare-Niemeyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method) or [d'Hondt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method). Of course, all these methods are doomed to fail in weird speciakl cases, such as splitting an odd number of cents equally among an even number of lines - unless ouy go into the fine print of these election  methods where ultimately a *random* decision is made for the last seats/cents.

Answer (score 1):

That strategy is ok, but I suggest you split all but the highest percentage value, so that the round-off gets added to the largest dollar value, in order to minimize the relative error. So in this case, 2.82 gets round up to 2.83, rather than rounding up 2.15 to 2.16.

In general, with a longer list of splits, the rounding error may be more than one cent. In that case, you should distribute the error amount one cent at a time to the invoices with the highest percentages / dollar values, so that no invoice is incorrect by more than one cent.

To do that,

1. Calculate a trial value for each invoice by rounding down,
2. Total the trial values,
3. Subtract the trial total from the true total to determine the total rounding error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will do some tests